# Passing parameters to a class component in REACT Expo

Tags: reactjs, expo

I am developping an application with REACT and Expo however having started recently and after having overcome some difficulties i am facing a problem that i cannot solve.
In my application I have a flatlist of products, flatlist which touch-sensitive invokes a screen whose exported component is a class.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Acquisti', {item})}}>    
        <Text style={styles.green}>Acquista</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

In the screen *Acquisti* is imputed a quantity.
When I touch another product the screen *Acquisti* show the precedent product, (I think because the parameters are captured in the constructor).

```
export default class Acquisti extends Component {   
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.cancella = "\u2718";
        prodotto = props.route.params.item;
        this.state = {
            Qty: '',
            Costo: 0,
            acquisti: [],
        };
    }
...
```

I believe that parameter retrieval must be included in the *render*, but I have no idea how to do it.

Thank for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I am slowly dropping in REACT, so yesterday I found my soluction.
Actually it is in the rendering that I have to access the data, so I modified the program in the following way (and it works):

````
export default class Acquisti extends Component {   
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
\\        prodotto = props.route.params.item;
        this.state = {
            Qty: '',
            Costo: 0,
            acquisti: [],
        };
    }
...
    render() {
      prodotto = this.props.route.params.item
      return (
...```
````